# Can I add a common function to a set of EntitySet<TEntity> Classes - LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, inheritance

I am using LINQ to SQL

and want to add functions to autogenerated `EntitySet< TEntity >` collections.

eg.

```
City.Houses
```

where `Houses` is automatically generated `EntitySet < House >`

I am using extension method to add extract function to the `EntitySet < House >` class

so that I can get something like

```
City.House.FindByID(id);
```

but now I also have

```
City.Bunglows.FindByID(id);
```

now `FindByID` basically does the same thing for both these classes.

Will I have to extend `Bunglows` also and implement the same function again. Can't I do some kind of inhertiance on the autogenerated `EntitySet< TEntity >` classes??

### Commenting on Andrew Hare's answer

But that will make FindByID() available on all EntitySet< TEntity > classes. What if I want to implement that function on these 2 particular entity sets only???

Answer (score 1):

Make your extension method generic like this:

```
public static TEntity FindByID<TEntity>
    (this EntitySet<TEntity> source, Int32 id)
{
    // ...
}
```

This will allow you to use this extension method on any closed constructed instance of `EntitySet<TEntity>` (i.e. `EntitySet<House>` or `EntitySet<Bungalow>`) as long as your implementation of `FindByID` can be appropriately expressed generically.

Comment: But that will make FindByID() available on all EntitySet< TEntity > classes. What if I want to implement that function on these 2 particular entity sets only???